# How can I give my GKE deployed application access to Google Pub/Sub?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-pubsub

I deployed a kotlin backend application that is utilizing google cloud pub/sub. I recently deployed that application with Cloud Run and it ran fine having full access to Pub/Sub.
Now because of reasons I have to deploy the application with GKE. However now the access to Pub/Sub seems not to work anymore.

I checked what service account my GKE Cluster is using and figured out it was the default one. Therefore I granted Permissions as `Pub/Sub Editor` to that service account.

[image]

I thought with this everything should work.

But still I see this error message in my logs:

```
com.google.api.gax.rpc.PermissionDeniedException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED: User not authorized to perform this action.
```

Any ideas what I have missed out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That could be 2 things:

- Either your pod use [Workload Identity](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity) and doesn't use the default service account (*with the editor role, thing to avoid by the way...*). And so, the service account that you use hasn't the PubSub permissions
- Or, because you use the default compute engine service account (*with the editor role, thing to avoid by the way... I repeat myself, but it's really bad!*), the [Node pool scope](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/access-scopes) are set by default (if you haven't override that parameters) and you can't access to the PubSub API because of credential scopes.

The best solution is to recreate your node pool, with a custom service account. Like that you can enforce the least privilege at node pool level, and you avoid the legacy compute engine scope definitions and limitations. If you use workload identity, you can go a level beyond in term of security and enforcing the least privilege at the pod level.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I use a GKE Autopilot cluster. Might that cause issues as well? Cause I have a hard time figuring out how to customize the service account for that Autopilot Cluster right now

Comment: By checking the documentation, it's the same behavior with GKE Autopilot: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/authenticating-to-cloud-platform#authenticating_with_service_accounts

Answer (score 0):

I think, it would be good to explain the particular workflow. **Autopilot** GKE clusters use Workload Identity by default, it's impossible to edit this configuration parameter (and that's good for sure).

Next, you need to make GKE pods communicate with GCP services in a proper way, that should be achieved by setting up the Kubernetes Service Account, GCP Service Account and connect them to each other. These are the steps how it could be done:

Prerequisites - let's set up the environment variables, that we gonna use:

```
$ export GCP_PROJECT_ID=__YOUR_PROJECT_ID__
$ export K8S_SA=__YOUR_KUBERNETES_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME__
$ export GCP_SA=__YOUR_GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FOR_K8S_NAME__
$ export K8S_NAMESPACE=__YOUR_KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE__
```

Create Kubernetes service account:

```
kubectl create serviceaccount $K8S_SA -n $K8S_NAMESPACE
```

Create GCP service account:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts create $GCP_SA --project=$GCP_PROJECT_ID
```

Assign GCP service account "Pub/Sub Editor" role (this is **very basic** approach, but it could be set up with more granular permissions through IAM, depending on your requirements):

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding $GCP_PROJECT_ID \
--member=serviceAccount:$GCP_SA@$GCP_PROJECT_ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
--role=roles/pubsub.editor
```

The Kubernetes way to know how to link service accounts is annotation, let's annotate our Kubernetes Service Account:

```
kubectl annotate serviceaccount $K8S_SA -n $K8S_NAMESPACE \
iam.gke.io/gcp-service-account=$GCP_SA@$GCP_PROJECT_ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

And finally, GCP should know which service account by the name of Kubernetes SA:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding \
$GCP_SA@$GCP_PROJECT_ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
--role roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser \
--member "serviceAccount:$GCP_PROJECT_ID.svc.id.goog[$K8S_NAMESPACE/$K8S_SA]" \
--project $GCP_PROJECT_ID
```

That's all, now your Kubernetes Service Account impersonates GCP Service Account and you can use it as usual in your deployments:

```
template:
  metadata:
    …
  spec:
    automountServiceAccountToken: false
    serviceAccountName: __YOUR_KUBERNETES_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME__
```